# Save request.POST to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

in **view.py:**

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def ipn(request):
    transactions_logger = logging.getLogger("django")
    processor = Ipn(request.POST, logger=transactions_logger)
    verification_success = processor.verify_ipn()
    encoding = request.POST.get('ok_charset', None)
    data = QueryDict(request.body, encoding=encoding)
    if verification_success:
        form = OkpayIpnForm(data)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("ALL FINE!!")
            form.save()

    return HttpResponse("")
```

In **forms.py:**

```
 class OkpayIpnForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OkpayIpn
        exclude = []
```

Code for IPN Check`processor = Ipn(request.POST, logger=transactions_logger`:

```
class Ipn(object):


   OKPAY_VERIFICATION_URL = 'https://checkout.okpay.com/ipn-verify'
   OKPAY_IPN_INVALID = b'INVALID'
   OKPAY_IPN_VERIFIED = b'VERIFIED'
   OKPAY_IPN_TEST = b'TEST'
   OKPAY_STATUS_COMPLETED = 'completed'

   __verification_result = False

   def __init__(self, request_data, logger):
      if 'ok_verify' in request_data:
        raise Exception("ok_verify must not be present in initial request data for {}".format(
            self.__class__.__name__
        ))
      self._request_data = request_data
      self.logger = logger
      return

   def verify_ipn(self):
       self.__verification_result = False
       headers = {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       }
       verify_request_payload = {
           'ok_verify': 'true',
       }
       verify_request_payload.update(self._request_data)

       resp = requests.post(self.OKPAY_VERIFICATION_URL, data=verify_request_payload, headers=headers)

       if resp.content == self.OKPAY_IPN_VERIFIED or resp.content == self.OKPAY_IPN_TEST:
        self.__verification_result = True
       # if resp.content == self.OKPAY_IPN_VERIFIED:  # anyway disable test on production.
       #     self.__verification_result = True
       return self.__verification_result
```

All is ok, I revice IPN and validate it, then I try to validate form and save it to Database.

But form doesn't pass validation and doesn't save to database.

Thank You for help

Comment: Try doing an `else` statement after your `if form.is_valid()` and do `print form.errors`. You can see why the form is not passing.

Comment: Big thx, the problem was that in model i CharField has maxlength=20 , but recived 40 symbols

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that 1 `CharField` of Model for saving IPN has `maxlength=20`,  but recieved 40 symbols.

Thx [jape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848774/jape) he advised to add in form validation `else` statement and print `form.errors`

the error of of form validation was :

```
<li>ok_item_1_type<ul class="errorlist"><li>Ensure this value has at most 20 characters (it has 40).</li></ul></li>
```